# Hyperledger genesis.block and TLS CA Cert

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Dears,

If i open a hyperledger fabric genesis.block, there are CA certificates in the block.
What I do not understand is why a "Transport Layer Security" CA cert has to be in the genesis.block.
Also note that in the documentation, it says that currently TLS CA certificates can not be revoked, which would be another reason NOT to include the TLS CA certs in the genesis.block.

If someone could shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

If you think there is a better place to ask this question please let me know.

Imad

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know.
If you enabled TLS mode on peers and orderers.
The block it self needs the cert to communicate with those nodes.
if that part left blank
at least when you got peer into channel and it start send broadcast to orderers, the latter would pump bad tls certificate message and deny the connection.